# Pros and cons for using web client vs web reference c#

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns, webclient

I have integrated 12+ odd web service to my application using simple webclient object.

I did not add any web reference just used WebClient.UploadData(url, byte[] data).

My request are built like following. Is this standard approach?

```
 XDocument doc= new XDocument(

                      new XDocument(
                            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", String.Empty),
                            new XElement(soapenv + "Envelope",
                               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soapenv", soapenv), new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "get", get),
                               new XElement(soapenv + "Header"),
                               new XElement(soapenv + "Body",
                                   new XElement(get + "GetRate",
                                       new XElement("rtRequest",
                                          new XElement(get + "account" + accountValue)



   string xstring = doc.ToString();
               byte[] Data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xstring);
               response = client.UploadData(RatingUrl, Data);
```

Comment: Your question is vague and possibly opinion based, but this doesn't look standard at all to me. Where did you find an example like this?

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I had never seen like that either , but one guy in team introduced this. I have been working in IT for almost 10 years and used WCF and regular asmx before.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a regular SOAP service, then no, this is not the preferred way to do it.  Use a web reference, it will generate the proxy classes for you based on the WSDL.  It will be easier, less error-prone, and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a *standard approach*.

In .NET world, Windows Communication Foundation is a recommended framework to interact with SOAP services. It wraps all the transport and message format things, so you don't have to hand-code it (as shown in your example).

Use [Add Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) to generate appropriate proxy class for your services.

Here's an [introduction article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee958158.aspx) that gives an overview of WCF.